# Was the whistle-blower's (12 Aug 2019) complaint deemed credible?

Tags: united-states, congress, impeachment, whistleblowers, trump-impeachment

Despite rhetoric to the contrary, did the Inspector General (Michael Atkinson- IGIC) determine that the whistle-blower's complaint appeared credible?

This question can be answered factually.  The question relates to a government process that resulted in a finding.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, from the August 26 letter from the Inspector General to the Acting Director of National Intelligence [as published by the NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/09/26/us/politics/whistle-blower-complaint.html#g-page-15):

> Having determined that the complaint relating to the urgent concern appears credible, I am transmitting to you this notice of my determination, along with the Complainant's Letter and Classified Appendix.

Answer (score 15):

The complaint "appeared credible" per the ["Office of the Inspector General of the Intelligence Community’s Statement on Processing of Whistleblower Complaints"](https://www.dni.gov/files/ICIG/Documents/News/ICIG%20News/2019/September%2030%20-%20Statement%20on%20Processing%20of%20Whistleblower%20Complaints/ICIG%20Statement%20on%20Processing%20of%20Whistleblower%20Complaints.pdf)

> In  summary,  regarding  the  instant  matter,  the  whistleblower  submitted  the  appropriate  Disclosure of Urgent Concern form that was in effect as of August 12, 2019, and had been used by the ICIG since May 24, 2018.  The whistleblower stated on the form that he or she possessed both  first-hand  and  other  information.    The  ICIG  reviewed  the  information  provided  as  well  as  other information gathered and determined that the complaint was both urgent and that it appeared credible.  From the moment the ICIG received the whistleblower’s filing, the ICIG has worked to effectuate Congress’s intent, and the whistleblower’s intent, within the rule of law.  The ICIG will continue in those efforts on behalf of all whistleblowers in the Intelligence Community.